# как найти значение в хеш таблице(словаре)?

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
class EGE2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    int size,i;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    hashMap.put("One", 1);
    hashMap.put("Two",2);
    hashMap.put("Three", 3);
    hashMap.put("Four", 4);
    hashMap.put("Five", 5);
    hashMap.put("Six", 6);
    hashMap.put("Seven", 7);
    hashMap.put("Eight", 8);
    hashMap.put("Nine", 9);
    hashMap.put("Ten", 10);
    hashMap.put("Twenty", 20);
    hashMap.put("Thirty", 30);
    size = scanner.nextInt();
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){
        String line = "";
        line = scanner.next();
        if(line.equals("stop")){
            break;
        Integer map = hashMap.get(line);
        System.out.println(map);
        }
     }
 }
```

Сначала я ввожу словами числа.
    Затем на вход программе подаётся значение N — количество записей, которые необходимо обработать
    Следующие N строк содержат записанные словами числа. Каждое число записано по-английски, маленькими буквами, 
    без ошибок. Если число состоит из нескольких слов, между словами находится ровно один пробел, 
    лишних пробелов в начале и в конце строк нет.
    Нужно чтобы программа определяла сумму входных чисел,которые ввожу словами

Comment: так если каждое число записано по-русски, то почему у вас записано по английски?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю вы хотите чтобы пользователь вводил какую-либо строку, после чего вы проходите по хеш-таблице и в случае если такая строка там есть, то берете оттуда числовое значение и все это суммируете в одну переменную.

```
int res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> map : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = map.getKey();
            Integer value = map.getValue();
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(key))
                res += value;
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```